# How to add Highcharts networkgraph in angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have included the highcharts module and I want to implement network graph of highchart in angular. Could you please help me out to implement it?

Please find the stackblitz link below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfytxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: `Please find the [main information elsewhere]` That is not how stack**overflow** works. You want a helpful answer *here*? [Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). *Here*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply you have to load **networkgraph module** and initialize it like that:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsNetworkgraph from "highcharts/modules/networkgraph";

HighchartsNetworkgraph(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/9o10wry80r

I recommend you using `highcharts-angular` official wrapper. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: please can you help me in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493387/highcharts-network-graph-custom-link-labels

Answer (score 5):

Thanks the solution @Wojciech Chmiel, it helped me a lot.

However with the latest version of the high charts, angular and other dependencies the above mentioned solution was not working. It was giving me below error

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("/node_modules/highcharts/modules/networkgraph")' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

The dependencies and the versions i have are as below

```
"@angular/animations": "^9.0.6",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
"@angular/common": "^9.0.6",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.0.6",
"@angular/core": "^9.0.6",
"@angular/forms": "^9.0.6",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.6",
"@angular/router": "^9.0.6",
angular-highcharts": "^9.0.2",
highcharts": "^8.0.4",
highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
```

The solution i have is

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsNetworkgraph from "highcharts/modules/networkgraph";
import HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

HighchartsNetworkgraph(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace * as  with import  HighchartsNetworkgraph from "highcharts/modules/networkgraph";

Comment: Does this add anything to Wojciech Chmiel's 2019 answer?