# Highcharts network graph custom link labels

Tags: graph, charts, highcharts, angular-highcharts

i'm trying to implement a network graph, and in my case the edges must be labeld. For example, i'm fetching data like this

[{from: "A", to: "B", "label":"text1"},{from: "B", to: "C", "label": "text2"}]

so in the graph it must be like this: A-----text1------B--------text2--------C

I've read the docs and there's the linkFormatter that can help me do this but i can't figure it out. I've tried to memic this question's answer [highchart network network-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046325/highchart-network-network-graph) that shows label on tooltip not the edges. Can please someone help me !!

Answer (score 1):

Use `linkFormat` or `linkFormatter` with the correct reference to the property, for example:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            allowOverlap: true,
            linkFormat: '{point.label}'
        },
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jfbwLhp3/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.dataLabels.linkFormatter